# Unable to see Box2DdebugRenderer's body outlines

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am using box2ddebugrenderer temporarily as of now to render the bodies into the world but I am not able the see the mono-color outlines of bodies being created in the world upon running.

This is the code of my game's Screen:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

static final int VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 20;
static final int VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 13;

World world;
Body ground;

final float TIME_STEP = 1 / 300f;
float accumulator = 0f;

OrthographicCamera camera;
private Box2DDebugRenderer renderer;

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //Clear the screen
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    renderer.render(world, camera.combined);

    accumulator += delta;

    while (accumulator >= delta) {
        world.step(TIME_STEP, 6, 2);
        accumulator -= TIME_STEP;
    }
}



@Override
public void show() {
    world = createWorld();
    ground = createGround(world);
    renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);
    camera.update();

}

public World createWorld() {
    return new World(Constants.WORLD_GRAVITY, true);
}

public Body createGround(World world) {
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(Constants.GROUND_X, Constants.GROUND_Y));
    Body body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(Constants.GROUND_WIDTH / 2, Constants.GROUND_HEIGHT / 2);
    body.createFixture(shape, Constants.GROUND_DENSITY);
    shape.dispose();
    return body;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to define BodyType of physics body in BodyDef

```
BodyDef bodyDef=new BodyDef();
bodyDef.BodyType= BodyType.STATIC;
```

value of different constant should be appropriate so that body lie within the camera viewport like you have 
Constants.GROUND_X,
Constants.GROUND_Y,
Constants.GROUND_WIDTH,
 
Constants.GROUND_HEIGHT

create small body and check, body outline is visible or not.
After this, still if you got nothing on screen draw simple Sprite using SpriteBatch.

One more condition 
May be you are overriding render method of Game in your Child Game class and not calling parent render method.